# how to get the path of cookies using ssjs?

Tags: cookies, xpages, serverside-javascript, ssjs

I am trying to get the path of a cookie

I have several cookies with the same name but with different paths.

The following example return null using the getpath() method

```
var request = facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest(); 
var cookies = request.getCookies();
print(cookies[1].getName()))
print(cookies[1].getPath()))
```

I also tried the global object "cookie" in xpages but how do I get the path from that?

How can I get the path of all the cookies using ssjs?

[image]

Comment: How do you get cookies with different paths? Share some code, pls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Googled a bit. Seems to be a common problem beyond Domino and XPages. Both `getDomain` and `getPath` return `null`, because browser does not send it to the server. Explained here [getDomain() of javax.servlet.http.Cookie is returning null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9080735/getdomain-of-javax-servlet-http-cookie-is-returning-null)

Also a short thought here https://coderanch.com/t/283519/java/Cookie-getDomain-returns-null that it may be security feature.

Answer (score 1):

Both ways of getting a cookie return a java.servlet.http.Cookie, which does have the getPath() method, which you're using. Are you sure the path is getting set? Looking at an POST request from an XPage (both via the servlet it's calling and FireBug), the DomAuthSessId and SessionID cookies don't have a path set, so getPath() returns null.

Comment: in one of my cookies I have a path set to the database "/mydb.nsf" but that still returned null. need to try that again

Comment: I added a picture in the topic of the cookies I try to read from