# Read parent domain cookies in java

Tags: java, cookies, session-cookies

I want to read parent domain(`domain.com`) cookies

Running the code from `xyz.domain.com`

```
Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
        if (cookies != null) {
            for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
           //only subdomain cookies(i.e. xyz.domain.com) are displayed

            }
        }
```

Here I am not getting domain.com cookies

Similar to the below link

[Access parent domain cookies from an application running on a subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23018531/access-parent-domain-cookies-from-an-application-running-on-a-subdomain)
**Update:**
Cannot edit the cookies .i.e. cannot set domain of the cookie

Answer (score 0):

When cookie is created in domain.com, you need to set domain as cookie.setDomain("."), Then cookie will be available in sub domain.